# How to select, copy and paste vector masks via JavaScript in Photoshop

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I am currently able to select active layers via:

```
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.copy();
```

and paste it

```
app.activeDocument.paste();
```

However the associated Vector and Pixel masks are not copied over.  Is there a way to copy the vector and pixel masks associated with the active layer as well?

Thank you!

EDIT:
I ended up using

app.activeDocument.activeLayer.duplicate(destinationDocument,ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);

Works exactly as I needed it to!

Answer (score 1):

The script listener is your friend when it comes to layer masks. As they are a bit of a pain.
Here's a function to select layer mask when given a layer name (assuming it exists)

You should be able to copy and apply it to the new layer

```
// FUNCTION SELECT MASK
function selectMask(LayerName)
{
  try
  {
    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref = new ActionReference();
    ref.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID('Chnl'), charIDToTypeID('Chnl'), charIDToTypeID('Msk ') );
    ref.putName( charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), LayerName );
    desc.putReference( charIDToTypeID('null'), ref );
    desc.putBoolean( charIDToTypeID('MkVs'), true );
    executeAction( charIDToTypeID('slct'), desc, DialogModes.NO );

    // =======================================================
    var id1083 = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
    var desc238 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id1084 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref161 = new ActionReference();
    var id1085 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
    var id1086 = charIDToTypeID( "fsel" );
    ref161.putProperty( id1085, id1086 );
    desc238.putReference( id1084, ref161 );
    var id1087 = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
    var ref162 = new ActionReference();
    var id1088 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
    var id1089 = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
    var id1090 = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
    ref162.putEnumerated( id1088, id1089, id1090 );
    desc238.putReference( id1087, ref162 );
    executeAction( id1083, desc238, DialogModes.NO );
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    //alert( "This layer has NO layer mask!" );
    activeDocument.selection.deselect();
  }
}
```